# Disable Auth doesn't work with BF nuget package 4.7.1

Tags: botframework

### Version

Microsoft.Bot.Streaming and Microsoft.Bot.Builder
"4.7.1"

### Describe the bug

For direct line speech local test, set `IsAuthenticationDisabledAsync` to true in building a `BotFrameworkHttpAdapter`. `SendActivityAsync()` fails to send response back with below error
`Failed to fetch token before processing outgoing activity. An IIdentity is required in TurnState for this operation.`

For webchat test, it failed at Conversation:: ReplyToActivityWithHttpMessagesAsync, I get 401 unauthorized issue

### To Reproduce

1. Update nuget package of BF to 4.7.1
2. Implement `public class DisabledAuthCredentialProvider : ICredentialProvider` which set `IsAuthenticationDisabledAsync` to true
3. Build `BotFrameworkHttpAdapterv` with `DisabledAuthCredentialProvider`
4. See exception in  `SendActivitiesAsync`
   `(await this.GetAppCredentialsAsync(this.GetBotAppId(turnContext), (string) null, new CancellationToken()).ConfigureAwait(false)).GetTokenAsync(false);`

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me (in Emulator). Running 4.7.1. Here's what I have in DisabledAuthCredentialProvider

```
public class DisabledAuthCredentialProvider : ICredentialProvider
    {
        public Task<string> GetAppPasswordAsync(string appId)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<bool> IsAuthenticationDisabledAsync()
        {
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }

        public Task<bool> IsValidAppIdAsync(string appId)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

I can share my bot if that helps.

Comment: I use the same class. there is no problem in sending request, but looks having trouble in getting response to channel. For example, in webchat test, Conversation:: ReplyToActivityWithHttpMessagesAsync returned unauthorized issue. Could you get the response message? Which adapter are you using?